# Throw an exception in powershell with nesting original error

Tags: powershell

I'm a C# developer who is trying to build something useful using PowerShell. That's why I'm keep trying to use well-known idioms from .NET world in PowerShell.

I'm writing a script that has different layer of abstractions: database operations, file manipulation etc. At some point I would like to catch an error and wrap it into something more meaningful for the end user. This is a common pattern for C#/Java/C++ code:

```
Function LowLevelFunction($arg)
{
  # Doing something very useful here!
  # but this operation could throw
  if (!$arg) {throw "Ooops! Can't do this!"}
}
```

Now, I would like to call this function and wrap an error:

```
Function HighLevelFunction
{
  Try
  {
     LowLevelFunction
  }
  Catch
  {
     throw "HighLevelFunction failed with an error!`nPlease check inner exception for more details!`n$_"
  }
}
```

This approach is almost what I need, because `HighLevelFunction` will throw new error and the root cause of the original error would be lost!

In C# code I always can throw new exception and provide original exception as an inner exception. In this case `HighLevelFunction` would be able to communicate their errors in a form more meaningful for their clients but still will provide inner details for diagnostic purposes.

The only way to print original exception in PowerShell is to use `$Error` variable that stores all the exceptions. This is OK, but the user of my script (myself for now) should do more things that I would like.

So the question is: **Is there any way to raise an exception in PowerShell and provide original error as an inner error?**

Comment: You can throw exceptions in PowerShell: `try { ... } catch { throw (New-Object System.Exception 'Some message.',$_.Exception) }`

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl. Is there any "powershell way" to do this?

Comment: IMHO, most "PowerShell way" would be use of `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` and `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` which are available to advanced functions.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately when throwing a new exception from the `catch` block as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583780/7571258), the script stack trace (`ErrorRecord.ScriptStackTrace`) will be reset to the location of the `throw`. This means the root origin of the inner exception will be lost, making debugging of complex code much harder.

There is an alternative solution that uses [`ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to define a high-level message and [`$PSCmdlet.WriteError()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528359/7571258) to preserve the script stack trace. It requires that the code is written as an [advanced function cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1). The solution doesn't use nested exceptions, but still fulfills the requirement *"to catch an error and wrap it into something more meaningful for the end user"*.

```
#------ High-level function ----------------------------------------------

function Start-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding()] param()

    try {
        # Some internal code that throws an exception
        Get-ChildItem ~foo~ -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        # Define a more user-friendly error message.
        # This sets ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails.Message
        $_.ErrorDetails = 'Could not start the Foo'

        # Rethrows (if $ErrorActionPreference is 'Stop') or reports the error normally, 
        # preserving $_.ScriptStackTrace.
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError( $_ )
    }
}

#------ Code that uses the high-level function ---------------------------

$DebugPreference = 'Continue'   # Enable the stack trace output

try {
    Start-Foo -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $ErrorView = 'NormalView'   # to see the original exception info
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
    ''
    Write-Debug "`n--- Script Stack Trace ---`n$($_.ScriptStackTrace)" -Debug
}
```

Output:

```
D:\my_temp\ErrorDetailDemo.ps1 : Could not start the Foo
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\my_temp\~foo~:String) [Write-Error], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,ErrorDetailDemo.ps1

DEBUG:
--- Script Stack Trace ---
at Start-Foo, C:\test\ErrorDetailDemo.ps1: line 5
at , C:\test\ErrorDetailDemo.ps1: line 14
```

Our high-level error message 'Could not start the Foo' hides the error message of the underlying exception, but no information is lost (you could access the original error message through `$_.Exception.Message` from within the catch handler).

**Note:** There is also a field `ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction` which you could set as you see fit. For simplicity I didn't use it in the sample code, but you could set it like this `$_.ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction = 'Install the Foo'`.

Comment: I love this answer because it addresses the need using the language features provided. Powershell has a sophisticated mechanism that integrates with the concept of streams, and it's good to raise awareness of the language idioms.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw a new exception in your `catch` block and specify the base exception:

```
# Function that will throw a System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptiopn
function Fail-Read {
  [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( 'C:\nonexistant' )
}

# Try to run the function
try {
  Fail-Read
} catch {
  # Throw a new exception, specifying the inner exception
  throw ( New-Object System.Exception( "New Exception", $_.Exception ) )
}

# Check the exception here, using getBaseException()
$error[0].Exception.getBaseException().GetType().ToString()
```

Comment: To output an exception including all nested exceptions: `try{ CodeThatThrows } catch { $_.Exception.ToString() }`. This outputs exception types and messages. One may also add `$_.ScriptStackTrace` to get the stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately throwing a new exception like this discards `$_.ScriptStackTrace`, so the origin of the inner exception will be lost. The script stack trace will start at the location of the `throw`. I haven't found a good workaround yet.

Comment: Couldn't you store the original stacktrace in a new variable and reference it? Or is it a reference to an object that gets wiped when a new exception is thrown?