# What's the right way to emit errors in powershell module functions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've read quite a bit on powershell error handling and now I'm quite confused about what I should be doing on any given situation (error handling). I'm working with powershell 5.1 (not core).
With that said:
Suppose I have a module with a function that would look like this mock:

```
function Set-ComputerTestConfig {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $Name)

begin { ... }
process { 
 # task 1
 # task 2 => results in a failure that prevents further tasks
 # task 3
 # task 4
}
end { ... }
```

Let's say that for each computer name that I pass to this function, I have 4 tasks to complete, but if any of the tasks fail, I can't continue with the remaining tasks.
How should I be producing an error (best practice) such that it halts "process" for this particular computer name but effectively continues to process the pipeline?

Comment: Why just not working  with a try catch block where all the four tasks are in a try block and the catching will continue on to the next computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **If you want to *continue* processing inputs from the pipeline, you must emit a *non-terminating* error**:

  - `Write-Error` writes non-terminating errors; it writes to PowerShell's error stream without generating an exception behind the scenes; execution continues normally.

    - If a .NET method call is the error source, as in your case, wrap it in `try` / `catch`, and call `Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_` in the `catch` block:

      - `try { <#task 1 #>; ...   } catch { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }`
    - Unfortunately, still as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4, `Write-Error` doesn't fully behave as expected, in that it doesn't set the automatic success-status variable, `$?`, to `$false` in the caller's context, as it should. The only workaround at present is to make sure that your function/script is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) one and to use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()`; *from a `catch` block* you can simply use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)`, but crafting your own error from scratch is cumbersome - see [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629).
- **If you want processing to *stop right away*, use a *terminating* error**:

  - `throw` creates terminating errors.

    - Unfortunately, `throw` creates a more *fundamental* kind of terminating error than binary cmdlets emit: **unlike the *statement*-terminating errors emitted by (compiled) cmdlets**, **`throw` creates a *script*-terminating (fatal) error**.

      - That is, by default a binary cmdlet's statement-terminating error only terminates the statement (pipeline) at hand and continues execution of the enclosing script, whereas `throw` by default aborts the entire script (and its callers).
      - [GitHub issue #14819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14819) discusses this asymmetry.
    - Again, the workaround requires that your script/function is an *advanced* one, which enables you to call `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` instead of `throw`, which properly generates a *statement*-terminating error; as with `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()`, you can simply use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)` *from a `catch` block*, but crafting your own statement-terminating error from scratch is cumbersome.
- **As for `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`**

  - This turns *all* error types into *script*-terminating errors, and at least ***advanced* functions / scripts - those expected to act like cmdlets - should *not* set it**.
  - Instead, make your script / function emit the appropriate types of errors and let the *caller* control the response to them, either via the common `-ErrorAction` parameter or via the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.

    - **Caveat**: Functions *in modules* do *not* see the caller's preference variables, if the caller is outside a module or in a different module - this fundamental problem is discussed in [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).
- **As for *passing errors through* / *repackaging* them from inside your function script**:

  - Non-terminating errors are *automatically* passed through.

    - If needed, you can suppress them with `-ErrorAction Ignore` or `2>$null` and optionally also collect them for later processing with the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter (combine with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`).
  - *Script*-terminating errors are passed through in the sense that the entire call stack is terminated by default, along with your code.
  - *Statement*-terminating errors are written to the error stream, but by default your script / function *continues* to run.

    - Use `try { ... } catch { throw }` to instead turn them into *script*-terminating errors, or ...
    - ... use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)` instead of `throw` to relay the error as a *statement*-terminating one.

**Further reading**:

- Guidance on when to emit a terminating vs. a non-terminating error is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).
- A comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling is in [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

Comment: As a newb to review queues, I've been down the rabbit hole. I find that answers like this are by far the exception, and they should be called out.

Comment: I always forget the syntax, here is an example: `$PSCmdlet.WriteError( [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new( [Exception]::new("MyMessage"), 'MyErrorId', [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidData, $MyTargetObject ))` -- of course you should use more specific exception type if possible and also adjust the `ErrorCategory`.